# Unset sessions after form success not working

Tags: codeigniter

When I deselect my check box in my **modify & access** permissions it does not **unset** it from sessions if form is submitted success full.

What I am trying to achieve is on my edit function if any check box is not checked then it will **unset from sessions** when form is submitted success full. Because the reason need it unset from sessions is because when user logs in the permissions modify and access are set into sessions.

**How can I make this work what I am after I have tried it in my edit but not unset when check box is empty**

If i use this `$this->session->unset_userdata('modify');` it unset all the modify array in sessions I just need it to unset the one that matches the unchecked check box.

```
public function edit() {

$this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

$this->model_user_group->editUserGroup($this->uri->segment(4), $this->input->post());

if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == TRUE) {

if (isset($_POST['permission[access]'])) {

$this->session->unset_userdata('permission[access]');

}

if (isset($_POST['permission[modify]'])) {

$this->session->unset_userdata('permission[modify]');

}

}

redirect('admin/users_group');

}

$this->getForm();

}

public function getForm() {
$data['title'] = "Users Group";

$this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

$user_group_info = $this->model_user_group->getUserGroup($this->uri->segment(4));

if ($this->uri->segment(4) == FALSE) {
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
} else {
    $data['name'] = $user_group_info['name'];
}

if ($this->uri->segment(4) == FALSE) {
    $data['user_group_id'] = $this->input->post('user_group_id');
} else {
    $data['user_group_id'] = $user_group_info['user_group_id'];
}

$ignore = array(
'admin',
'dashboard',
'filemanager',
'login',
'menu',
'register',
'online',
'customer_total',
'user_total',
'chart',
'activity',
'logout',
'footer',
'header',
'permission'
);

$data['permissions'] = array();

$files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

foreach ($files as $file) {

    $permission =  basename(strtolower($file), '.php');

    if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
        $data['permissions'][] = $permission;
    }

}

$permission_access = $this->input->post('permission');

if (isset($permission_access)) {
    if (isset($permission_access['access'])) {
        $data['access'] = $permission_access['access'];
    } elseif (!empty($user_group_info['permission']['access'])) {
        $data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
    } else {
        $data['access'] = array();
    }
}

$permission_modify = $this->input->post('permission');

if (isset($permission_modify)) {
    if (isset($permission_modify['modify'])) {
        $data['modify'] = $permission_modify['modify'];
    } elseif (!empty($user_group_info['permission']['modify'])) {
        $data['modify'] = $user_group_info['permission']['modify'];
    } else {
        $data['modify'] = array();
    }
}

$this->load->view('template/user/users_group_form.tpl', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found away to get it working I have got sessions from database then re set the sessions in form, without using unset_sessions();

```
public function edit() {

    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

        $this->model_user_group->editUserGroup($this->uri->segment(4), $this->input->post());

        $user_group_query = $this->db->query("SELECT permission FROM " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user_group 
            WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$this->session->userdata('user_group_id') . "'");

        $permissions = unserialize($user_group_query->row('permission'));

        $this->session->set_userdata($permissions);

        redirect('admin/users_group');

    }

    $this->getForm();
}
```